# Flutter camera image to api

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am at the Point where i call the Flutter Camera package, take a photo and save it temporary in my app using pathProvider. Now i want so upload this image to an api using the Dio package. My pathprovider is able to give me a String with the Path to the image. With this path i am able to display the Image using the Image widget from Flutter. however i am not able to send it to an api.

```
processImage(file) async {
    print(file);
    // /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7915E945-4582-4586-8062-F73537283283/Library/Caches/2019-07-22 13:35:36.243335.png

var newfile = File(file);

Dio dio = new Dio();

FormData formData =
    new FormData.from({"size": "auto", "image_file": newfile});

try {
  final response = await dio.post(
    "YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    data: formData,
    options: Options(
      headers: {'X-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXX'},
    ),
    onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
      print("send $sent / $total");
    },
    onReceiveProgress: (int sent, int total) {
      print("receive $sent / $total");
    },
  );
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
  // that falls out of the range of 2xx and is also not 304.
  print(e);
}

// print(response);
  }
```

Comment: What does `not able to send it to an api`  mean? Any error?

Comment: I am getting a 400 wich means "input file unprocessable". image_file needs to be 
a string($binary)

Comment: What is the server expecting? Is it expecting a `bas64` string?

Comment: no just a file in a FormData. i guess i can convert it into base64 and send it there. But i think it is not nessesary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dio library that has a class called `UploadFileInfo` which you can use for your case:

```
FormData formData =
    new FormData.from({
            "size": "auto", 
            "image_file": UploadFileInfo(newfile, "file_name.txt")},
        );
```